# Registration of New Users using passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm working on a freecodecamp [challenge](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/information-security-and-quality-assurance/advanced-node-and-express/registration-of-new-users/). I'm trying to register a user and login the same user but couldn't do it successfully.

I've tried various methods by changing my code a couple of times but still was not successful.

```js
// Register

app.route('/register').post((req, res, next) => {
      db.collection('users').findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, user) {
          if(err) {
            console.log('error')
              next(err);
          } else if (user) {
            console.log('redirect to home-page')
              res.redirect('/');
          } else {
              db.collection('users').insertOne({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}, (err, doc) => {
                    if(err) {
                      console.log('error after recored')
                        res.redirect('/');
                    } else {
                      console.log('error with user', doc);
                        next(null, user);
                    }
                }
              )
          }
      })},
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req, res, next) => {
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });
```

I have the complete code [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/advanced-node--and--express) for your reference.

I should be able to register and it directs me to my profile.

Login successfully and redirect to the profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code that you have referenced, you seem to have a typo in the Passport local strategy handler.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
      function(username, password, done){
        db.collection('user').findOne({username: username}, (err, user) => {
```

The collection here should be `users` as the Register route creates a entry in the `users` collection.

Comment: Your'e welcome. Please mark the answer correct if it solves your problem